# Collect output of top command displayed with separate option

Tags: linux, command-line-interface, top

I would be grateful to you for some details about the top command output achieved using the hotkey "A". I suppose the it gives back the swap usage per PID: it is right, isn't it? 
Could you please explain me what does mean SWAP = 11m ?
Moreover, it is possible to redirect this output, displayed in such way, to a file? My need should be to collect those data through some hours then analyse them...

Answer (score 0):

Everything you need is to execute the command `man top`. All questions are answered there. Even the `-b` switch for collecting data over time.

But you probably should use a monitoring software instead of the plain top.